# Who are the author of the principle "everything is permitted that does not contradict the freedom of others"?

Tags: reference-request, freedom

Who are the author of the following philosophical principle?

> everything is permitted that does not contradict the freedom of others

Where are roots of this principle?

Comment: Not sure about the exact formulation, or where, But it sounds like John Stuart Mill: - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stuart_Mill

Comment: Something similar in [Kant](https://books.google.it/books?id=uSXf4dBLsusC&pg=PA458&lpg=PA458).

Comment: *Declaration of the Rights of Man and of the Citizen* ( Déclaration des droits de l'homme et du citoyen de 1789), set by France's National Constituent Assembly, drafted by the Abbé Sieyès and the Marquis de Lafayette, in consultation with Thomas Jefferson: **Article IV – Liberty consists of doing anything which does not harm others.**